# Flutter background notifications using API call

Tags: api, flutter, push-notification

I'm looking to find a solution to how I can send notifications to a user of an app when an API is updated

```
{"error":"none","data":[{"status_text":"Completed","status_id":"6","name":"Billy","order_id":"26173","type":"type1"}]}
```

The above code is from the API call which is a URL being used within the app, but I'm wondering how I can display a notification to the user when the status_text field is updated, for example, if it said 'being sent out' then changes to 'completed', how could I send a local notification letting the user know

I've done quite a bit of research but not found any solutions that work for me as of yet, would really appreciate any help

Comment: Best way is to have a server that does this and sends push notifications to the user, but if you really want it done on the device then you can use the android alarm manager package which calls the API periodically (say every 1 hour) in the background and you could then send a notification based on your condition https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager

Comment: Hi @Billy Noyes I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution ?